# Fill Spline based curves efficently

Tags: mesh, splines

As you can see on the image below, I got a lot of vertices after converting the splines to a mesh. The splines a drawn manualy from an old map.

[image]

I already started with the filling process. Selecting two edges and fill them with `F`was not a solution, since it causes weird looking artifacts.So my second attempt is to select "nearest" vertices manualy and fill a edge between. This seems a bit tedious and a lot of work.

Does anybody have a good approach to this?

I have a silly Idea in mind: Using a clothing simulation to fall down on my splines and use the fianl result as my shape. Does this sounds like a good Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select 2 vertices and create an edge as shown on your screenshot.
Then active edge selection mode (<kbd>2</kbd>), and spam <kbd>F</kbd> which creates faces until the end of the spline is reached. Select the whole spline by pressing <kbd>L</kbd> (*Select Linked*), then remove all faces (<kbd>X</kbd>, *Only Faces*)

Comment: Thats a very good hint. Is there also a fast way to create an equal number of vertices on the "curves"? and spread them even?

Comment: I used limited desolve which worked great. The manual workload is reduced drasticly and the result is looking great.